# Canadian re-entering Canada from U.S. with expired Passport but Nexus in good standing

Tags: passports, canadian-citizens, nexus

At the airport, I discovered my passport had expired. I always enter the U.S. with Nexus. I was able to finally enter into the U.S. but was warned and probably flagged and might have troubles re-entering Canada. Can anyone please advise what to do now? Visit a Consulate in the U.S.? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: When is your return flight? In any event, do not bother to visit a consulate. [Government of Canada consular offices in the United States do not provide passport services. You must send your application by mail.](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/renew-adult-passport/how.html) There appears to be an exception for urgent circumstances, but you should call first in such a case.

Comment: User has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.